# How can I use a column as "K" in the Percentile function for DAX/PowerBI?

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have two columns, one with values and one with random decimal numbers ranging from 0-1. I want to be able to apply the following function:

```
Percentile.Inc( [Column1], [Column2])
```

Answer (score 0):

This is syntax use rule. --> `PERCENTILE.INC(<column>, <k>),`

- You must use k value in dot(.)
- k must between 0 and 1. Otherwise return error. You can't assign another column instead .

[image]